# Replacing a string on 2 lines

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to edit a file on the command line.
I need to modify a set of 2 lines in this file.

Here are the 2 lines:

```
<parameter name="mail.smtp.from">synapse.demo.0@gmail.com</parameter>
    </transportSender>-->
```

Here is the result I would like to have:

```
<parameter name="mail.smtp.from">synapse.demo.0@gmail.com</parameter>
    </transportSender>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's a sed related question more than a WSO2IOT question, isn't it?

You already removed comment tag start and I suppose the line of the comment close tag is not unique…

Is line number a constant?
you could get your line number:

```
sed -i "`grep -n -A1 synapse.demo.0@gmail.com file.xml|tail -n1 | cut --delimiter="-" -f1`s/-->//" file.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use command line editors like vi. It comes with almost all Unix systems. You can edit the file entering into insert mode. You can refer the following link.
[Basic vi commands](https://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html)

Comment: I think Tof want to make a script, not use anything interactive.

Answer (score 0):

**Perl**

`perl -lpe 's|</transportSender>-->|</transportSender>|' your-file` **Just Once**

`perl -lpe 's|</transportSender>-->|</transportSender>|g' your-file` **multiple**

---

**To save in-place**

`perl -i -lpe 's|</transportSender>-->|</transportSender>| your-file'` **find and edit and save all together**